# JavaScript Video/Audio Interruption Event

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

My goal is to collect the total time the user views a given media, in this case, video. I've read through both [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) and [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to identify whether there's an event to handle the following scenario:

A user is watching a video, but before having completed the video, they close the browser. In this scenario, `ended` isn't triggered, and in my case, calling `currentTime` is operationally expensive since it means we have to call our servers every second to pass the seconds information for the video for each user that's viewing the video.

When the browser closes, we have no way to pass any information to our analytics server since the session is stopped.

Are there any events that can be triggered from the browser to the server to inform us whether the video was:

1. Interrupted?
2. How far did the user see the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering this from the browser is going to be tricky as, clearly, the user closing the browser 'should' stop it from dong anything else. Even if the browser does some controlled shutdown and clean up you will likely find this will be browser specific.

On the server side, on the other hand, most videos are streamed in chunks, either with simple HTTP byte range requests or via a segmented ABR streaming protocol like HLS or MPEG-DASH.

The browser requests the video chunk by chunk as the user is watching it, so the server will see when a particular user has stopped requesting chunks.

Some (most?) analytics systems will accept inputs from server events as well as client events and provide some mechanism to correlate them, so you could use this server side event to give you the data you need. For example, Google Analytics, supports server events, although it is hidden under the confusing title (IMO) 'Measurement Protocol' (link correct at time or writing and is just given as an example - lots of other analytics services also):

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

The data is sent to Google analytics as a HTTP POST and includes info like the Google analytics tracking id and a client id - see this example from their documentation of a payload:

```js
v=1              // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555         // Anonymous Client ID.
&t=              // Hit Type.
```